# What is the difference between a LEFT JOIN and a sub-query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to find all of the results in table1 that do not have an associated record in table2. I have 2 queries:

1. `SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.table1_id WHERE table2.table1_id IS null`
   This works and returns all of the results in table1 that are not in table 2
2. `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id NOT IN (SELECT table2.table1_id FROM table2)` This does not work. It returns zero results. I've ran each of the parts individually and it appears this should work.

Will someone please explain why one works where the other doesn't

Edit: Added purpose of queries

Edit 2: Added sqlFiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ab473/1 It works on here, so I have no idea why it isn't working on my local computer

Edit 3: sqlFiddle replicating the issue http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bd92f7/1. Removing the null value resolved the issue.

Comment: Are there any table2.table1_id null values?

Comment: No, in the database there are no records where table2.table1_id is null. There are only null values because of the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: I am unable to replicate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e8572/1 So this is most likely an issue with your data (although I'm having a hard time imagining what that could possibly be to cause this behavior).

Comment: Can you add the table definition for both the tables. also add the insert statements also if possible.

Comment: [NOT IN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-NOTIN): "Note that if the left-hand expression yields null, or if there are no equal right-hand values and at least one right-hand row yields null, the result of the NOT IN construct will be null, not true. This is in accordance with SQL's normal rules for Boolean combinations of null values.". So are there any `NULL` values in `table2.table1_id`?

Comment: Does this work? `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT table1_id FROM table2 WHERE table1_id IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @PraveenP The table definition (that applies to the query) is basically the sqlfiddle JNevill posted. The only difference is that I'm using uuid instead of int.

Comment: fwiw, I'd expect the `JOIN` to be faster, anyway, and I'd expect `NOT EXISTS` to be faster than both.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help. @jarlh It looks like there was a null value. In another query in my sql file I was inserting a new record without filling that in.

Answer (score 2):

I think that both of your queries are not ideal:

- The first query can return a row from `table1` more than once if there is more than one matching row in `table2`. Sure, you can fix that with a `DISTINCT`, but the performance is not ideal.
- The second query won't work if there is a row in `table2` where `table1_id IS NULL`:

  - `x NOT IN (1, 2, NULL)` is equivalent to `x <> 1 AND x <> 2 AND x <> NULL`
  - now `x <> NULL` is always NULL, no matter what `x` is
  - `<anything> AND NULL` is never TRUE
  - so the condition with never be TRUE, which explains why you get no result

The best (and most efficient) query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2
                  WHERE table1.id = table2.table1_id);
```

Comment: Somehow I'm not convinced that in PostgreSql a `[NOT] EXISTS` is generally more efficient than a `LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL`.

Comment: @LukStorms: `NOT EXISTS` is definitely more efficient than `NOT IN` (and correct on top of that). In my experience, **if** there is a difference between a NOT EXISTS and a LEFT JOIN .. IS NULL, then the NOT EXISTS version is faster. But most of the time they are pretty much identical.

Comment: It is like the horse says, and saving on the `DISTINCT` (if you need it) would be a win.